# SQL Server after split col. into row want to add some words with some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello everyone come here again to ask for help.

I have a table format as follows:

```
ID     NAME
01F    A-B
03F    C-D
```

Split this table by "-" as this format:

```
ID    NAME
01F   A
01F   B
03F   C
03F   D
```

After do this, I want to add a new row with some conditions.

Create a new table like this:

```
NEWID    ID    NAME
01F_I    01F   A
01F_D    01F   B
03F_I    03F   C
03F_D    03F   D
```

There are 321 row in the table I split out. I have no ideal to add this col.

```
select t1.ID, s.items NAME
from my tablename t1
outer apply splitfunction (t1.NAME, '-') s
```

Here is my split code.

Please give some suggestions to fix my table to what I need.

Thanks a lot & BR

Comment: "There are 321 row in the table I split out. I have no idea to add this row." Which row? I only see a new column NEWID, there is no new row.

Comment: Sorry, my fault add a new col.

Comment: Can you give an example of what conditions you need to apply for the new col?

Comment: According to NAME.  NAME A-B, NEWNAME A as initial(I) so newname= ID+initial(I), and B as destination(D) so newname=ID+des(D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    CASE WHEN s.items = SUBSTRING(t1.Name,1,CHARINDEX('-',t1.Name)-1) THEN t1.ID + '_I' ELSE t1.ID + '_D' END AS NEWID
    ,t1.ID
    ,s.items NAME
from 
    mytablename t1
    outer apply splitfunction (t1.NAME, '-') s
```

Comment: this script make all NEWID= ID+'_D'. There are no NEWID=ID+'_I'

Comment: what is the data in your mytablename? Is the name like A-B or is it ab-efg?

Comment: Some row A-B, AC-DC, or ABC-DEF. Thx

Comment: @Tiger93 - I have edited the answer. See if it returns correct data now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative set based approach would be to forget the OUTER APPLY and use a UNION.

```
Select ID+'_I' as NewId, ID, left(name,charindex('-', name)-1)
From table
Union all
Select ID+'_D', ID, right(name,charindex('-', reverse(name)) - 1)
From table
```

I've just sketched that out without testing, but I think it'll do what you want.